# Changing text within jqueryUI dialog button after it is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I change the text for the cancel button from CANCEL to CLOSE?  Thanks!

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons     : [
        {
            text    : 'SAVE',
            click    : function() {}
        },
        {
            text    : 'CANCEL',
            click    : function() {}
        }
    ]    
});
$("#button").click(function(){alert('Please change cancel button text from "CANCEL" to "CLOSE"');});

<div id="dialog"><button id="button">Change cancel button text from "CANCEL" to "CLOSE"</button></div>
```

Comment: Write 'CLOSE' instead of 'CANCEL'?

Comment: @ExplosionPills.  Want it to start off with given text of "CANCEL", but when later the user clicks the button, the text will change to "CLOSE".  Note that the button is within the dialog.

Comment: Have you tried the setter from the documentation? http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: @greener No, but reading it right now.

Comment: @greener  Maybe I don't understand, but I don't think this applies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify class name to your dialog, and select UI buttons from the class.

```
$('#foo').dialog({
    buttons: {
        CANCEL: function() {
            alert(1);
        }
    },
    dialogClass: 'my-dialog'
});
$('.my-dialog .ui-button-text:contains(CANCEL)').text('CLOSE');
```

Comment: Thanks mattn.  Didn't know about dialogClass.  Seems like it will work.  I also don't know about how you used ...uton-text:contains(CANCEL).  Will you please elaborate?  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 haha, It's possible to write `$.each('.my-dialog .ui-button-text', function(){...})` but too long for me. ;)

Comment: Understood about typing too much :)  Still uncertain how this will work.  I will experiment.

Comment: `ui-button-text` class elements are not located with non-related your dialog. So it can't use selector passed from dialog class. So I put dialogClass to the dialog. Then you can use selector through over the dialog class. And `contains()` is sizzle selector that can select element which contains specified text. i.e. this code changes is possible to change dialog buttons dyamicaly.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  Sorry but getting sleepy and will not be able to confirm til tomorrow.

Answer (score 9):

It is a really simple thing :)

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( {
    "buttons" : [
    {
        id: "my-button",
        text: "My button",
        click:function() {
            $("#my-button span").text( "Our button!:)" );
        }
    } ]
} );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the text of the button outside the initialization ([documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }]
});
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ] );
```

You can also bind it to an event.

Comment: Thanks greener.  How does this target the cancel button and not the save button?

Comment: It doesn't. But am I right in guessing that you're changing the text as a result of data being sent to the server ('Save') and want to present the user with a button to close the dialog?

Comment: Pretty much as you say.  A new dialog is open which shows an open input form with a cancel/save button.  User clicks cancel and it obviously closes.  User clicks save, and the open input changes to non-editable text (but there is an edit button nearby), and the cancel button change close.  User clicks the edit button, and the close dialog buttons change from close to cancel

Comment: So in fact it's Save/Cancel then Edit/Close. Save and Edit have their own behavior and because Cancel/Close are the same (they close the dialog), you just want to change the text. Seems like mattn's solution fits. Alternatively, write all the buttons and hide and show as required.

Comment: Yes, I started to go down the create too button approach, but thought there had to be a better awy.

Answer (score 0):

Important to add the []

```
buttons: [{
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
```